# How to replace a PAE kernel with non PAE Kernel?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, pae, non-pae

After reading the information from my Question [pros/cons of PAE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151068/for-a-32-bit-kernel-what-are-the-pros-cons-of-pae-vs-non-pae) , i want to remove PAE kernel because i don't need them . I know removing  a kernel from Synaptic Package Manager . Thats easy job but how to get Non-PAE kernel of current ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install a different kernel (such as a non-pae kernel), you would need to install the package for it. Use your favourite package manager (like Synaptic) to install `linux-image-generic`, or use this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

In **Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier version**, this will install the latest generic kernel that is not pae. Then you would need to reboot and in the grub menu select the non-pae kernel. Once it boots up, verify everything is working.

In **Ubuntu 12.10 or later version**, this will NOT work since linux-image-generic is equivelent to linux-image-generic-pae.

Optional: You can remove the other kernel once you know everything is working with the new kernel by doing

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic-pae
```